# Does boost::asio support local in-memory connections?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I'm thinking about creating a server/client application with an optional standalone operation mode.

In this standalone mode, it wouldn't create a real TCP server/client, just 2 threads, communication with each other using a memory buffer.

Based on the ASIO docs, I'm certain it can be achieved using the generic stream protocol and a custom protocol implementation, but is there an easier or already existing way of doing this?

Comment: It's probably fastest just to bind your server address to localhost. It'll almost certainly just work, and be plenty fast enough.

Comment: I'm not sure about the speed, but it's certainly not a performance problem. I'm just curious if there is an easy solution to this, but there are also two practical, but marginal reasons I have in mind: paranoid firewall rules blocking localhost connections, and testing the networking code without outside factors involved

Comment: The next easiest is to use a system pipe, and there is code implementing a pipe transport for ASIO easily available via Google. Be aware that pipes on Windows have major gotchas, they do work very well with enough prodding, but expect substantial debugging effort to get them working well. i.e. avoid if you can just use localhost instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Asio does not have first-class support for this functionality.

However, Asio does support some platform specific stream oriented types that work with Asio's I/O operations (`read()`, `async_read()`, `write()`, `async_write()`, `read_until()`, and `async_read_until()` free functions):

- [local::stream_protocol::socket](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/local__stream_protocol/socket.html) uses UNIX Domain Sockets (local sockets).  These would provide the closest parity to TCP sockets.  A program can tests if their platform supports this via the `BOOST_ASIO_HAS_LOCAL_SOCKETS` macro.  See the [UNIX Domain Sockets](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/posix/local.html) overview for more details.  If the application protocol is essentially message based and using TCP for its reliability, then it can be worth considering using UDP over local sockets as they have guaranteed reliability.
- [POSIX Stream-Oriented File Descriptors](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/posix/stream_descriptor.html): pipes, standard input and output, and various devices, but not regular files.  A program can tests if their platform supports this via the `BOOST_ASIO_HAS_POSIX_STREAM_DESCRIPTOR` macro.
- [Windows Stream-Oriented HANDLEs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/windows/stream_handle.html): named pipes.  This requires using the I/O completion port backend.    A program can tests if their platform supports this via the `BOOST_ASIO_HAS_WINDOWS_STREAM_HANDLE` macro.

Be aware that these are often used for interprocess communication, so they may accessed locally by other programs.

Comment: Each time I consider supporting a standalone mode, I weight out the operational benefits (I/O throughput, not necessarily application throughput) over the technical debt it introduces.